# Layered Navigation (different attributes)

Tags: magento2, attributes, layered-navigation

Help me please. 
I am trying to figure out why my left sidebar layered navigation just shows two attribute colors instead of three.

For example: I have 2 products
Product1 black and orange,
Product2 black and blue.

But, the color filter shows only blue and orange options.
[image: color options]

Why is the black not appearing in the layered navigation options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have color filter set for `Filterable (with results)` there are only filters that contain any product. This is one possible reason for attribute's option to nit be displayed in layered navigation.

But for black option this is not a point there. Both products have black in their option, so filtering by black color doesn't matter, because in list there will be still two products. Notice, that blue an orange are only for one product - so if you choose one of these option form layered navigation you will see changes in collection.

So logic is - if filter doesn't change collection it won't be displayed.

To see it clearly, try uncheck black color for one of your products.

Comment: Although your answer is logical but I think that there's a problem. If colors are not visible all, the customer doesn't know what her options are. The option may be not only color but also eg job (mechanic, masonry etc.). He will not known: What occupations there are the website?

Comment: But if anything is fine with your code they all be visible if you change your attribute to be `Filterable (no results)` - try this one, but notice that if you change it you willl display all filter items , even if they don't have any products assigned. 

If you want to have all filters visible all the time (and you have products to all your filters possiblities, so don't need to set to be `filterable (no results)` you can refractor module to change default behavior, but it needs custom coding.

Comment: @BartoszKubicki i have set Filterable (with results) there are products with different weight and but yet its not getting displayed on frontend. Product attribute and attribute set have been enbaled in sales->product. Do i have to do any changes in configuration->catalog